# Post or Get data not present from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to validate the value entered in a text input field using an ajax request to the server however when I try to access the post or get data, they are both empty arrays.

The html input:

```
<input type="text" name="club_key" id="club_key" class="form-control" onblur="verifyKey(this);">
```

The JavaScript:

```
function verifyKey(ev)
{
    var url = '/index.php?/orders/key';
    // url = encodeURIComponent(url);

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: ev.value
    }).done(function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
```

The server side PHP:

```
public function check_key()
{
    echo '<pre>';
    echo "Clubbbed to death: ";
    // print_r($this->input->get_post());
    print_r($_GET);
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Both are empty arrays. There is no post or get data present. The site is a CodeIgniter site, so in the routing I have:

```
$route['orders/key']    = "orders/check_key";
```

I have also tried:

```
$route['orders/key/(:any)'] = "orders/check_key/$1";
```

Any ideas why there's no post data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP expects form submissions (via get and post) to be in a `key = value` format. Your `data: ev.value` is JUST a value: `ev.value`. Since there's no key, PHP cannot put anything into $_GET or $_POST, because all array entries must have a key.

Try

```
data: {foo: ev.value}
```

and then

```
$_POST['foo']
```

Alternatively, you could try

```
$value = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

which will read that bare string directly from the input, but it'll be completely unprocessed by PHP.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you!

I guess I was reading the documentation on the .ajax method in JQuery wrong because it states that data can be an object or a string.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: it can be. you can pass in a pre-made string, but it still has to end up equivalent to `key=value&key=value` type stuff when it gets to PHP.

Comment: Right, and I know that, or at least should know that after more than 12 years of coding!   :P

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use, instead

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: { club_key : jQuery('#club_key').val() }
}).done(function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

data element should be an object, not a scalar.